# jquery autocomplete 2 textboxes by using same data array and sort accordingly

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I got two textboxes.

```
<input type="text" id="text1"> <input type="text" id="text2">
```

What i want to get them to be autocompleted by using the same array like:

```
var data = [
    { value : "1" ,   label1 : "Matt",    label2 : "0101 Matt" },
    { value : "2" ,   label1 : "John",    label2 : "0203 John" },
    { value : "3" ,   label1 : "Chris",   label2 : "0102 Chris" },
    { value : "4" ,   label1 : "Sam",     label2 : "0401 Sam" },
    { value : "5" ,   label1 : "George",  label2 : "0302 George" },
    { value : "6" ,   label1 : "Amy",     label2 : "0205 Amy" },
];
```

I need `label1` field in the array to be the main label for autocompleting when user focuses on `text1` textbox and `label2` field when focusing on `text2` textbox. Also need the result list to be sorted in alphabetical order accordingly.

I believe this has something to do with adding some code to open event or _renderItem extension of autocomplete but couldnt figure out so far.

Comment: have you tried any code yet??

Comment: Yes. I checked `http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data` and in the source section, line 65 `.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem` function seems to be excatly what i want but didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution**

**CODE**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
        var data = [
            { value : "1" ,   label1 : "Matt",    label2 : "0101 Matt" },
            { value : "2" ,   label1 : "John",    label2 : "0203 John" },
            { value : "3" ,   label1 : "Chris",   label2 : "0102 Chris" },
            { value : "4" ,   label1 : "Sam",     label2 : "0401 Sam" },
            { value : "5" ,   label1 : "George",  label2 : "0302 George" },
            { value : "6" ,   label1 : "Amy",     label2 : "0205 Amy" },
        ];

        $('#text1').focusin(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.au').html('')
            $nwArr = [];
            for($i=0;$i<data.length;$i++){
                $nwArr.push(data[$i].label1)
                $nwArr.sort(); 
            }
            for($i=0;$i<$nwArr.length;$i++){
                $(this).siblings('.au').append('<div>'+$nwArr[$i]+'</div>')
            }

        })
        $('#text2').focusin(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.au').html('')
            $nwArr = [];
            for($i=0;$i<data.length;$i++){
                $nwArr.push(data[$i].label2)
                $nwArr.sort(); 
            }
            for($i=0;$i<$nwArr.length;$i++){
                $(this).siblings('.au').append('<div>'+$nwArr[$i]+'</div>')
            }

        })
        $('#text1,#text2').focusout(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.au').html('')
        })
    })
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/5jtU7/

Hope it helps you :)